# Can I use a sub-domain on the same server as CDN?

Tags: php, cdn

My users will upload lots of images and I need to display them in a gallery. I have 2 specific questions:

1. Shall I create a sub-domain (e.g. `cdn.mydomain.com`) and upload the images there to load the images faster? I want to implement CDN technology on same server.
2. If answer to my above question is yes, is it necessary to keep the sub-domain name "cdn"? Or, can I also name it like `gallery.mydomain.com` ?

Thank you all for your time.

Regards,

Partha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of a [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) is to alleviate the load of your server and/or reduce lag for users far from your server so it really wouldn't make your images load any faster to have it on the same server, and could even be really counter productive once [http2 rolls in](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/02/http2-finished-coming-to-browsers-within-weeks/). But yes you can use a subdomain that's how it is usually done in your case. 
As for the sudomain's name it is a matter of preference and possibly SEO.

If you can't afford another server yet you can develop it as you would if it was on another server and just migrate everything later.